# OR condition in `if` statement

Tags: ruby

Why is

```
if name.eql? 'Name1' || name.eql? 'Name2'
  # doSomething
end
```

not allowed in Ruby? What is the good practice to do this in Ruby?

Comment: Maybe you could use a regex.

Comment: Additionally `==` is better practice in this case and removes the ambiguity. e.g. `if name ==  'Name1' || name ==  'Name2'` is valid and identical in the case presented.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the good practice to do this in ruby?

Parenthesizing method calls to avoid silly ambiguities.

```
if name.eql?('Name1') || name.eql?('Name2')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [case-expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression):

```
case name
when 'Name1', 'Name2'
  # do something
when 'Name3'
  # do something else
else
  # if all else fails
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ruby gives us the option to omit parenthesis and delegate the responsibility to the interpreter. what you've done is confuse the ruby interpreter because your lack of parentheses is ambiguous. Ie, ruby can't figure out what you're trying to do

this can be viewed a number of ways if we specify each parens

```
if(name.eql?('Name1') || name.eql?('Name2'))

if(name.eql?('Name1' || name.eql?('Name2'))

if(name.eql?('Name1')) || name.eql?('Name2')
```

a good practice is to specify parens when it starts to become ambiguous. Here that would mean putting them on the method arguements

```
if name.eql?('Name1') || name.eql?('Name2')
```